# XPath locator is not Working on this webpage

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I would like to click the Table of content list using Xpath, but Xpath is completely not working in this URL
https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ecam/contents/

Comment: what is the exception

Comment: can you provide few xpath ?

Comment: What you have done in the script ?

Comment: //*[@id="content"]/div[2]/ul/li[2]

Comment: Xpath is completely not working, the above is one list item in table of contents

Comment: have you tried css Selector

Comment: it is not working even when i am directly copying by right clicking element in inspect

Comment: You could share your code that we can see what you tried and what the problem is.

Comment: @scooprealm : Have you tried with provide css selector ?

Comment: @scooprealm as per your question see my answer with XPath. yet using CSS Selector is better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS Selector in place of XPath as follow :

**CSS Selector :** `a[href='/journals/ecam/2019/']`

**Code to click :**

```
content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='/journals/ecam/2019/']")
```

Comment: using CSS Selector is better then XPath! good answer!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are having problems with XPath...

This code snip works fine for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ecam/contents/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="TableofContentsNav"]').click()
all_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="middle_content"]//*[@href]')
for i in all_links:
    print(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

Hope you find this helpful!